# Complex Numbers Modulus

Tags: complex-numbers

In complex numbers modulus, one of the rule is

$|Z_1+Z_2|$ $\le$ $|Z_1|$ + $|Z_2|$

Is this rule also the same for a number?
Like for example,

$|Z_1+5|$ $\le$ $|Z_1|$ + $|5|$

Comment: Yes because 5 is also a complex number

Comment: Sure, expanding a little on the above comment, for $z_1=a+bi$ and $z_2=c+di$ then the inequality states that $(a+c)^2+(b+d)^2\leq a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$ which is clearly true for all $a, b, c, d >0$ and in particular with your $z_2=5+0i$, $(a+5)^2+b^2>a^2+b^2+5^2$.

Comment: Thanks! Alright so i am trying to solve a problem

Comment: You shouldn't be asking that question. In the first inequality, $Z_2$ can be any complex number, including $5$.

Comment: Your problem asks to find a lower bound to $ |Z_1+1| + |Z_2+1| + |Z_1Z_2+1| $. If you apply the triangle inequality to $|Z_1+1| + |Z_2+1| + |Z_1Z_2+1| $ you will only obtain an upper bound. So you need to try something else. Can you interpret the conditions $|Z_1|=1$ as a geometric object?